# How to Pass List values as parameters in SQL Java

Tags: java, sql, list, prepared-statement

I have one sql query (Copying values from one table to another table in same database ) where it takes multiple values as parameters and values are from list.

Below is which I have tried.Though I am not getting any error, but its not working.I want to insert values into database
    List EmployeeIDList= new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(123,823,456,890));
    List SalaryList= new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(14437,14297,13846,13441));

```
con1=DriverManager.getConnection(URL1,DB_UserName,DB_Password);
log.info("Data base connection is established");        
for (int i=0,j=0;i<EmployeeIDList.size();i++,j++) {
    stmt = con1.prepareStatement("Insert INTO Employee(Name, Year, EmployeeID, Tax, Salary)                 
            Select Name, Year, EmployeeID, Tax, Salary 
             (Employee

                       when EmployeeID= ? then ?   // 1st ? = EmployeeID,2nd ? = Salary
                       when EmployeeID = ? then ?         
                       when EmployeeID = ? then ?
                       else ?  // ? = Salary
                       end ) as Employee
                "From Employee2 + 
                "Where EmployeeIDin (?)");

        stmt.setInt(1,SalaryList.get(j));
        stmt.setInt(2,EmployeeIDList.get(i));           
        System.out.println("first salry is " +SalaryList.get(j))    ;
        System.out.println("first Employeeid is " +EmployeeIDList.get(i))   ;
        rs = stmt.execute();
```

When I execute "select * from Employee " in sql ,its not returning any values.

Note:If I execute above Insert query in sql,it works fine.Only through java I am not able to insert the values.

Comment: Huh?  This sql makes no sense.

Comment: What you're looking for is a batch insert after performing a single select, or some stored procedures to do some magic.

Comment: Your explanation is not clear enough. Please add some sample data and the expected result.

Comment: @OldProgrammer It works fine in sql when you Replace ? with values in query.I am trying to copy values from one table to another table.This I have written in Java

Comment: @TheImpaler I am trying to copy values from one table to another table.This I have written in Java. "?" in query takes list values as parameters.IExpected result is as I mentioned in question When I execute select * from Employee it should return data

Answer (score 0):

please try these code
String query = " Insert INTO Employee(Name, Year, EmployeeID, Tax, Salary)"
        + " values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
and then apply select query

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solution.There was wrong in Numbering the position in setInt.Thank you everyone